# Angular 2 Material SideNav always open on desktp and normal on mobile

Tags: angular, angular-material

I made this simple side nav in angular 2 material.
I want to keep oppened="true" only for desktop and keep the default behavior for mobiles and laptops.
This used to be present in Angular JS material. How do I implement this in Angular 2 ?

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <md-sidenav #sideNav>
    <md-nav-list>
      <a>One</a>
      <a>Two</a>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button md-icon-button (click)="sideNav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>

</button>
<span>Title</span>
  </md-toolbar>

  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: I did not used it yet, but i think your answer is here https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Comment: have a look at my answer below with demo

Answer (score 6):

@vinagreti pointed out the incredibly useful angular/flex-layout project, which reintroduces some of the layout functionality that used to be part of Angular Material, but was removed in versions 2+. I was already using that library so it was pretty easy to use it in conjunction with the sidenav from Angular Material to do what you've described here: have a sidenav that is always open on large screens, but toggleable on smaller screens.

You can make use of the disableClose, mode, and opened attributes of the sidenav component to get what you want.

The markup:

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav [ngClass.xs]="{'full-width': true}" [disableClose]="isSidenavCloseDisabled" [mode]="sidenavPosition" [opened]="isSidenavOpen">
...Contents of Sidenav go here....
</md-sidenav>
```

The component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  watcher: Subscription;
  sidenavPosition = 'side';
  isSidenavOpen = true;
  isSidenavCloseDisabled = true;

  constructor(media: ObservableMedia) {
    this.watcher = media.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      if (change.mqAlias === 'xs') {
        this.sidenavPosition = 'over';
        this.isSidenavCloseDisabled = false;
      } else {
        this.isSidenavOpen = true;
        this.isSidenavCloseDisabled = true;
        this.sidenavPosition = 'side';
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy () {
    this.watcher.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling myself a bit for this similar post, I used what seems like a bit of a hack that I found at https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1130, and which I've put in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5m19GQuag9zeqSdRUpMs).

The key in this solution is that it checks the media size on open, and on resize event, showing/hiding the side navigation panel depending on width available.  Credit for this goes to [sikemullivan](https://github.com/sikemullivan)

```
ngOnInit() {
    window.onresize = (e) => {
      this.checkMenu();
    };
    this.checkMenu();
  }

  checkMenu() {
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      if (w > 450) {
        this.start.open();
      } else {
        this.start.close();
      }
    });
  }
```

I call it a hack, because handling this through a resize event handler seems like taking out a sledge hammer to solve the problem. I would think there's something easier, but couldn't find anything easier myself.

Another issue with the above, is that if you're like me, maybe you'd like something that **keeps** open, then you'd need an answer to [Prevent md-sidenav from being closed using Escape key when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797909/prevent-md-sidenav-from-being-closed)

Comment: Can you please simply the answer. I don't totally get it

Comment: simplify the answer? or simply answer?  I'll try a bit of both.  Let me see.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **disableClose** property as below

```
 w = window.innerWidth;
      constructor(){
        if (this.w > 450) {
        this.disableClose=true;
      } else {
        this.disableClose=false;
      }
```

HTML will be as

```
<md-sidenav-container class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    Main content goes here
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" [disableClose]="disableClose">
<!---------------------------above line-------------------------------->
   Manu bar
  </md-sidenav>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ETICmUdjTlUm3X8NeaOM?p=preview)**

Comment: This is bit too low level, it is better to do it with material design + flex-layout like @Engineer_Andrew suggested

Comment: I explained the down vote in my previous comment. Andrews solution is the right way, and it should be the right answer.

Comment: @TuukkaLindroos did you get a chance to look into the demo??