# Prevent md-sidenav from being closed using Escape key when opened

Tags: angular, material-design

Using Angular2 & Material 2, how do I prevent `md-sidenav` from being closed.

Right now, I'm using

```
 <md-sidenav-container>
          <md-sidenav #start mode=side>
              <div class="flex-container" fxLayout= "column">
                  <button md-button md-raised-button [routerLink]="...
                  <button md-button md-raised-button [routerLink]="...  
                  <button md-button md-raised-button [routerLink]="...        
                  <button md-button md-raised-button [routerLink]="...           
             </div>
          </md-sidenav>
          <div>
                  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
 </md-sidenav-container>
```

With a crazy hack in `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {MdSidenav} from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test'

  @ViewChild("start") private start: MdSidenav;
  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone)  { }

  // XXX Shouldn't need this to force sidenav to open
  ngOnInit() {
    // angular material 2 doesn't have md-is-locked-open anymore.
    // this is my crappy hack.
    window.onresize = (e) => {
       this.checkMenu();
    };
    this.checkMenu();
  }

  checkMenu() {
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      if (w > 450) {
        this.start.open();
      } else {
        this.start.close();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Which kludgingly gets the job done. But even then, pressing ESC (for example) closes the sidenav, and I just don't want that!

I've got a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5m19GQuag9zeqSdRUpMs) which illustrates the problem.  Try clicking in the pink area, and pressing escape.  You'll see the sidenav close.

There was a `md-is-locked-open` directive prior to Angular 2, but that does not seem to exist anymore.  `fxshow` would seem to be promising, but I can't get it to work.

Sneaking some extra questions in here too.  In same above, how to make `router-outlet` always take "remaining of screen" thus ensuring that `md-sidenav` doesn't get an unnecessary scrollbar if `router-outlet` has a small height

Comment: Modified version of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679858/angular-2-material-sidenav-always-open-on-desktp-and-normal-on-mobile)

Comment: In deed, with a slight nuance.  This technically answers that post (I've put the answer there too), but some (I do), may wish for more: how to prevent closing.

Comment: Not a duplicate, changed title a tiny bit.  The other post is about automatically opening / closing.  This is about preventing closing.